# Android set custom ringtone in 4.4

Tags: android

I facing issue in android 4.4 ,setting custom ringtone.The below code works perfectly till andriod 4.2 .Some one please help me on this.The notification tone is set ,but am hearign only default beep sound.

I see exception :

```
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915): Writing exception to parcel
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/167 from pid=729, uid=1000 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:457)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:394)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:387)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openFile(ContentProvider.java:297)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:232)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.MediaPlayer._setDataSource(Native Method)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:991)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:972)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:921)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.setDataSource(MediaPlayer.java:874)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.Ringtone.setUri(Ringtone.java:180)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.RingtoneManager.getRingtone(RingtoneManager.java:593)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.RingtoneManager.getRingtone(RingtoneManager.java:384)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at com.android.providers.media.RingtonePickerActivity.run(RingtonePickerActivity.java:324)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 06:31:43.361: D/(163): openContentUri(content://media/external/audio/media/167) caught exception -1
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/MediaPlayerService(163): Couldn't open fd for content://media/external/audio/media/167
01-13 06:31:43.361: E/MediaPlayer(15915): Unable to create media player
01-13 06:31:43.361: D/Ringtone(15915): Problem opening; delegating to remote player
01-13 06:31:43.361: D/ActivityManager(729): checkComponentPermission() adjusting {pid,uid} to {163,1013}
01-13 06:31:43.371: D/MediaPlayer(928): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915): Writing exception to parcel
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/167 from pid=729, uid=1000 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:457)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:394)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:387)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openFile(ContentProvider.java:297)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:232)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:404)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.IRingtonePlayer$Stub$Proxy.play(IRingtonePlayer.java:151)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.media.Ringtone.play(Ringtone.java:223)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at com.android.providers.media.RingtonePickerActivity.run(RingtonePickerActivity.java:329)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5031)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
01-13 06:31:43.371: E/DatabaseUtils(15915):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-13 06:31:43.371: D/ActivityManager(729): checkComponentPermission() adjusting {pid,uid} to {163,1013}
01-13 06:31:43.381: D/(163): openContentUri(content://media/external/audio/media/167) caught exception -1
```

Java code

```
  File k = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + file_main);

        ContentValues cont = new ContentValues();
        Log.i("tag", "uri =" + k.getAbsolutePath());
        Log.i("tag", "uri =" + Uri.fromFile(k).toString());

        cont.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, Uri.fromFile(k).toString());
        // cont.put(MediaStore.AUTHORITY, Uri.fromFile(k).getAuthority());
        cont.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE,
                "*" + file_main.split("\\.")[0]);
        cont.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mpeg");
        cont.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.SIZE, Long.valueOf(k.length()));
        cont.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        cont.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
        cont.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        cont.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        cont.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, true);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(Uri.fromFile(
                k).toString());
        context.grantUriPermission("android.media.MediaPlayer", uri,
                Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        context.getContentResolver().delete(
                uri,
                MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA + "=\"" + k.getAbsolutePath()
                        + "\"", null);

        Uri newUri = context.getContentResolver().insert(uri, cont);
        Log.i("tag", "uri =" + newUri.toString());
        Log.i("tag", "uri authority =" + newUri.getAuthority());
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefa`enter code here`ultRingtoneUri(context,
                RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);

        Toast.makeText(`enter code here`
                context,
                values[pos]
                        + " is added to  Notification and set as Notifiacaion tone",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```